# Berry flux of magnetic monopole

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, magnetic-monopoles, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am sorry if it looks stupid question. I want to ask how sin is transferred back from spherical to Cartesian and how $F_{ij}$ tells us about magnetic monopole in magnetic field. $F_{ij}$ is berry curvature.

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.